# i/o timeout error using progrium/docker-consul

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, consul

I'm attempting to set up a production-ready cluster on AWS that uses [Jeff Lindsay's](http://www.progrium.com) [`progrium/docker-consul`](https://github.com/progrium/docker-consul) image to install `Consul` on each host but can't get the secondary and tertiary servers to `-join` the initial server.

I've followed the [Running a real consul cluster in production](https://github.com/progrium/docker-consul#running-a-real-consul-cluster-in-a-production-environment) instructions but I'm getting an `i/o timeout` error when my `consul2` and `consul3` nodes attempt to `-join` the `consul1` private IP.

**The Instances**

I spun up three `t2.micros` on AWS and got the following Private IP's assigned in my VPC:

```
172.31.4.194 (Intended to be `consul1`, leader)
172.31.4.195 (Intended to be `consul2`)
172.31.4.193 (Intended to be `consul3`)
```

**Starting Up The Initial Consul Server Instance**

My `consul1` node gets itself up and waiting for the other two just fine:

```
sudo docker run -d -h consul1 --name consul1 -v /mnt:/data \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8300:8300 \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8301:8301 \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8301:8301/udp \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8302:8302 \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8302:8302/udp \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8400:8400 \
    -p 172.31.4.194:8500:8500 \
    -p 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp \
    progrium/consul -server -advertise 172.31.4.194-bootstrap-expect 3
```

**Attempting To `run` The Second Server Instance**

But then when I attempt to start my `consul2` node, using the following:

```
sudo docker run -d -h consul2 --name consul2 -v /mnt:/data \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8300:8300 \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8301:8301 \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8301:8301/udp \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8302:8302 \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8302:8302/udp \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8400:8400 \
    -p 172.31.4.195:8500:8500 \
    -p 172.17.42.1:53:53/udp \
    progrium/consul -server -advertise 172.31.4.195 -join 172.31.4.194
```

**The Error**

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
==> WARNING: It is highly recommended to set GOMAXPROCS higher than 1
==> Starting raft data migration...
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Starting Consul agent RPC...
==> Joining cluster...
==> dial tcp 172.31.4.194:8301: i/o timeout
```

Any idea of what could be causing this? I've re-attempted about nine times and still no luck. It did spur me to do some more learning about networking (which is a broad, deep, fascinating subject) but I can't figure out if there's an issue in my config, or if this is an actual bug.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem Solved!**

Turns out that I had forgotten to open up the ports that `Consul` needs to use in the Security Group that governs access to the instances.

Opened up `8300`,`8301`,`8302`,`8400`, and `8500` and all installed just fine.

Comment: The alternative setup (which is [recommended](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/)) is to use the docker host network (*--net=host*); that way you don't need to do the docker container port mappings, and it should move faster. You still need your firewall to open up the ports of course.